# Do restaurants use acidified pesto?

Tags: food-safety, pizza

Do pizza restaurants usually make their own pesto or use commercial acidified pesto? Found pesto squished between plates this morning (about 11 hours old) and concerned about a low-acid situation and how to clean it up safely. Or this this a non-issue even if not acidified?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what is a ‘low-acid situation’ regarding pesto and why would it be alarming?

Comment: @Spagirl it was me overestimating the risk of botulism. Because they add citric acid to commercial pesto to prevent this.

Comment: It is possible to contract wound botulism, but this is extremely rare. Once upon a time it was a battlefield issue. These days it happens on occasion to drug users who inject. Most cases of botulism (also quite rare these days) occur when contaminated food is ingested.

Answer (score 4):

first question: it depends on the pizza restaurant, smaller pizzeria *might* do the pesto in house, bigger pizza chains will use commercial pesto.

second question: in the case of washing, normal (very hot water and soap) washing procedure will clean up everything.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this varies widely.  Some restaurants make their own, while others purchase it already prepared.  Whether or not it is acidified should have nothing to do with clean up.  If you are at home, scrape off what you can, simply soak in warm, soapy dish water, and scrub clean.  Alternately, use a dishwasher.   In a restaurant, follow the wash and sanitize procedure.